# CAN receive randomly, temporarily fails

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, interrupt, can-bus, nxp-microcontroller

I'm using `MK60FX512VMD15` processor for my **master** and using `CAN` bus to communicate with baudrate at `1Mbps`.

During a flashing sequence, the **master** communicates with a **slave** in a very simple pattern:

**master** sends 
`PROGRAM THIS DATA`
`d0 06 ef 4e 6a d1 94 4e`

and **slave** replies `SUCCESS`
`ff`

repeated thousands of times

```
148.5361 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 43 56 d9 08 7d f1 
148.5363 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5368 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 92 76 a9 e6 55 88 
148.5370 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5376 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 4b 4b 8e e7 a5 7c 
148.5378 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5402 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 79 d3 27 6b 94 27 
148.5404 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5409 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 76 de 49 b5 02 d9 
148.5410 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5416 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 ca 81 f1 9a 61 73 
148.5418 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5423 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 35 7c af eb 7d df 
148.5425 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5431 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 13 56 29 4c bb 82 
148.5433 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff                      
148.5438 1 7fe                    Rx d 8 d0 06 ce 18 61 06 ca d6 
148.5439 1 7ff                    Rx d 1 ff
```

**PROBLEM**

The vast majority of flashing attempts, there is no problem. But, every once in a while, the **master** will not receive the **slave**'s `SUCCESS` aka `0xFF`.

What I mean is that the receive interrupt on the **master** will not fire even though the **master**'s controller+transceiver does ACK the message on the physical CAN level.

To debug this problem, I increment `counter_prg` *in the Tx interrupt* when I send a `PROGRAM` command and increment `counter_ack` *in the Rx interrupt* when I receive `0xFF`.

When the timeout happens due to not receiving expected `0xFF`, a breakpoint is hit in the application sw-level and I see that `counter_prg != counter_ack` i.e. `counter_ack = counter_prg - 1` *even though I can see the slave's 0xFF on the bus and the controller+transceiver ACKS on the physical level*

There is no other traffic on this CAN bus.

**QUESTION**

What possible reasons are there for this happening?

I'd also appreciate any debugging strategies.

Comment: You should check the values of CAN bus State Registers... (`CANx_ESR1`??)

Comment: @oxuf turns out it was a race condition.